# How to get 3d metric values from disparity map?

Tags: python, opencv, 3d

I need to achive 3d metric values from disparity, cv2.reprojectImageTo3D makes points in 0,01s but values aren't in meters,my loop makes it in 4s(640x480 disp image).

```py
for v in range(dysp.shape[0]):
        for u in range(dysp.shape[1]):
            d = dysp[v, u]
            if d > threshold:
                z = (f * b / d)  
                x = ((u - cx) * b / d - (b / 2))  
                y = (v - cy) * b / d  
                points.append([x,y,z]);
```

How can I improve my loop or transform reprojectImageTo3D result to metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping over arrays is slow in Python. You must vectorize your code to make it fast.

The length unit of the 3D points depends on the length unit of translation vector `T` which you have obtained from `cv2.stereoCalibrate()` and which in turn depends on the length unit of the `objectPoints` passed to `cv2.stereoCalibrate()`.

`cv2.reprojectImageTo3D()` should do what you write in your loop (except that it doesn't subtract b/2). It will return an image with size=(480, 640, 3) and dtype=float32. So there is a 3D point for each image location. Invalid disparity values (negative numbers) will be handled according to the `handleMissingValues` parameter for `cv2.reprojectImageTo3D()`. (Check if your disparity values are positive)

If the disparity array has dtype=int16 the disparity values are encoded as fixed point numbers and you have to divide disparity values by 2^N (N is the number of bits for the fractional part). If you have used OpenCV's BlockMatching N will be 4.

Comment: After vectorizing:my_way: (480, 640, 3) time= 46.88  ms
reproject (480, 640, 3) time= 15.62  ms.It's almost 100x faster than before.Thank you for your answer.